# Migrating MySQL View to Oracle 12c

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am migrating a view from MySQL 5.0 to Oracle 12c. This is the code and part of the output in MySQL:

```
select tb1.courtUuid AS courtUuid,
tb1.uuid AS caseRecordUuid,
tb1.statusCode AS statusCode,
tb1.caseTrackingId AS caseTrackingId,
tb1.instantiationDateTime AS created,
crs.description AS caseRecordStatusDescription,
lct.description AS caseTypeDescription,
lcc.description AS caseTypeDescription2,
max(crh.eventDateTime) AS lastEventDateTime,
eventType.code as event_code,
eventType.description AS lastEventDescription,
tb8.firstName AS defendantFirstName,
tb8.lastName AS defendantLastName,
concat(lawyer.firstName,' ',lawyer.lastName) AS lawyerName,
lawyer.uuid AS lawyerUuid 
from tb1 
join tb2 crs 
join tb3 lct 
join tb4 lcc 
join tb5 crh 
join tb6 eventType 
join tb7 pp 
join tb7 lawyerPP 
join tb8 
join tb8 lawyer 
where ((tb1.caseTypeCode = 1) 
and (tb1.clearFilingFlag = 0) 
and (tb1.deletedFilingFlag = 0) 
and (tb1.archivedFlag = 0) 
and (tb1.statusCode = crs.code) 
and (tb1.localCaseTypeCode = lct.code) 
and (tb1.localCaseCategoryCode = lcc.code) 
and (crh.eventTypeCode = eventType.code) 
and (tb1.uuid = pp.caseRecordUuid) 
and (pp.relationshipCode = 2) 
and (pp.personUuid = tb8.uuid) 
and (tb1.uuid = crh.caseRecordUuid) 
and (lawyerPP.personUuid = lawyer.uuid) 
and (lawyerPP.relationshipCode = 4) 
and (lawyerPP.caseRecordUuid = tb1.uuid))
group by crh.caseRecordUuid
order by crh.caseRecordUuid
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IALLj.png)

This is the code in Oracle 12c, and part of its output:

```
select max(tb1.courtUuid) AS courtUuid,
max(tb1.uuid) AS caseRecordUuid,
max(tb1.statusCode) AS statusCode,
max(tb1.caseTrackingId) AS caseTrackingId,
max(tb1.instantiationDateTime) AS created,
max(crs.description) AS caseRecordStatusDescription,
max(lct.description) AS caseTypeDescription,
max(lcc.description) AS caseTypeDescription2,
max(crh.eventDateTime) AS lastEventDateTime,
max(eventType.code) AS code,
min(eventType.description) AS lastEventDescription,
max(tb8.firstName) AS defendantFirstName,
max(tb8.lastName) AS defendantLastName,
max(lawyer.firstName || ', ' || lawyer.lastName) AS lawyerName,
max(lawyer.uuid) AS lawyerUuid
from tb1 
join tb2 crs
on (tb1.statusCode = crs.code)
join tb3 lct 
on (tb1.localCaseTypeCode = lct.code)
join tb4 lcc 
on (tb1.localCaseCategoryCode = lcc.code)
join tb5 crh
on (tb1.uuid = crh.caseRecordUuid)
join tb6 eventType
on (crh.eventTypeCode = eventType.code)
join tb7 pp 
on (tb1.uuid = pp.caseRecordUuid)
join tb7 lawyerPP
on (lawyerPP.caseRecordUuid = tb1.uuid)
join tb8 
on (pp.personUuid = person.uuid)
join tb8 lawyer 
on (lawyerPP.personUuid = lawyer.uuid)
where ((tb1.caseTypeCode = 1) 
    and (tb1.clearFilingFlag = 0) 
    and (tb1.deletedFilingFlag = 0) 
    and (tb1.archivedFlag = 0)
    and (pp.relationshipCode = 2)
    and (lawyerPP.relationshipCode = 4))
    group by crh.caseRecordUuid
    order by crh.caseRecordUuid
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CQxF.png)

The output for the code in Oracle 12c should be the same than in MySQL.  The output for all the other columns is the same, but for the column code (in MySQL) and CODE (in Oracle) the output is different, as well as for column description_3 (in MySQL) that should be the same as LASTEVENTDESCRIPTION (in Oracle). The marked rows do not match.

I need the GROUP BY clause in Oracle to have only the crh.caseRecordUuid since otherwise, I would not get the same number of rows as in MySQL.  Adding more columns to the GROUP BY clause adds more rows to the output.  The output should be the same as it is in MySQL.

Please, if you can, help me figure this one out.

Comment: The original doesn't use aggregate functions, except for `max(crh.eventDateTime) AS lastEventDateTime`

Comment: Your have a `GROUP BY` with one key in MySQL and with numerous unaggregated columns.  MySQL is explicit that the values returned come from *indeterminate* rows.  Therefore, whatever Oracle returns is compatible with MySQL.  If you have a specific requirement, you'll need to understand the requirement and re-implement the query.